# Excel VLOOKUP for multiple values

Tags: excel, database, spreadsheet, vlookup

I have an array of cells and I want excel to return the same value for more than one cell. as an example,

If the cell says BG or CE or TF I want it to return “1”
If it says KR or TA or MN I want it to return “2”
And so on.
How would this work? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `=IF(OR(A1="BG",A1="CE",A1="TF"),1,IF(OR(A1="KR",A1="TA",A1="MN"),2,"..."))`

Comment: @J.Fox I think you could post that as an answer with some basic explanation

Comment: @J.Fox, would definately work. But it's the "and so on" from OP that is a bit worriesome (correct English?). Would be wise to have a list to refer to using INDEX/MATCH imo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would be perfect for a `VLOOKUP()` (with the exception that I don't know what "...and so on" refers to).

If your data is in column A, and you want to put the `1` or `2` in column B, you just create a separate table:

[image]

then use this formula in `B1` and drag down:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$F$6,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: ( @DanielG.Gabori - If this works for you, you can mark it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post. This will also remove the question from the "unanswered" queue.)